# Registering sub server(login) to master server - Photon Server -CJR Gaming MMO Framework

Tags: c#, server, mmo, photon

I am following Christian Richards tutorial on MMO Development using Photon Server. For those who don't know what that is, it essentially covers re-writing the photon framework from scratch, using an MMO type architecture. I have encountered numerous problems that I have either found work-arounds or fixes for, but this error I am stumped. I encounter the following error after the server starts and loads my proxy server and login server. The server starts up fine, looks for it fine, but as soon as it tries to register the sub server, it throws this error in my proxy log.

Proxy server log:

2015-07-22 14:56:10,892 [1] INFO  Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] Application stop: AppId=Proxy

2015-07-22 14:57:01,913 [1] INFO  Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - Application start: AppId=Proxy; AppPath=C:\Photon\deploy\ComplexServer, Type=ComplexServer.ComplexProxyServer

2015-07-22 14:57:01,968 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating AverageCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:01,977 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:01,986 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:01,993 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,001 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,008 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,017 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,026 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,035 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,043 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,051 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,058 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,066 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''

2015-07-22 14:57:02,084 [13] DEBUG Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - OnInit - ConnID=2, IP 127.0.0.1 on port 4520, type = TCPListener

2015-07-22 14:57:02,108 [13] DEBUG Photon.SocketServer.Protocol [(null)] - Parsed init message for application Master, client version 3.0.5, protocol GpBinaryV2 version 1.6

2015-07-22 14:57:02,120 [11] DEBUG MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonConnectionCollection [(null)] - Received init request 127.0.0.1:4520 - Photon.SocketServer.InitRequest

2015-07-22 14:57:02,127 [11] DEBUG MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonApplication [(null)] - Received init request from sub server

2015-07-22 14:57:02,154 [11] DEBUG Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - OnInit - response sent to ConnId 2 with SendResult Ok

2015-07-22 14:57:02,331 [7] ERROR Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonRequest.MMO.Framework.IMessage.get_Code() in c:\Programming\SoftwareDevelopment\C#\MMO\MMO.Photon\Application\PhotonRequest.cs:line 48
   at MMO.Photon.Server.PhotonServerHandlerList.HandleMessage(IMessage message, PhotonServerPeer peer) in c:\Programming\SoftwareDevelopment\C#\MMO\MMO.Photon\Server\PhotonServerHandlerList.cs:line 140
   at MMO.Photon.Server.PhotonServerPeer.OnOperationRequest(OperationRequest operationRequest, SendParameters sendParameters) in c:\Programming\SoftwareDevelopment\C#\MMO\MMO.Photon\Server\PhotonServerPeer.cs:line 36
   at Photon.SocketServer.ServerToServer.ServerPeerBase.OnReceiveInternal(Byte[] data, SendParameters sendParameters, Int32 rtt, Int32 rttVariance, Int32 numFailures) in h:\svncontent\photon-socketserver-sdk_3.4\src\Photon.SocketServer\ServerToServer\ServerPeerBase.cs:line 196
   at Photon.SocketServer.PeerBase.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__5() in h:\svncontent\photon-socketserver-sdk_3.4\src\Photon.SocketServer\PeerBase.cs:line 706
   at ExitGames.Concurrency.Core.DefaultExecutor.Execute(List`1 toExecute) in d:\dev\exitgames-libs\src\Core\Concurrency\Core\DefaultExecutor.cs:line 21
   at ExitGames.Concurrency.Fibers.PoolFiber.Flush(Object ) in d:\dev\exitgames-libs\src\Core\Concurrency\Fibers\PoolFiber.cs:line 216
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

*So as you can see, it sends the init responses/requests properly to the main server and login, until it tries to register the sub server. One can see from observing the Login.log below, as well as by comparing the time stamp on the 'registering sub server', the exception above is thrown almost a second after the login server tries to register the sub server.

2015-07-22 14:56:10,845 [1] INFO  Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - Application stop: AppId=Login
2015-07-22 14:57:01,541 [12] DEBUG Photon.SocketServer.ServerToServer.TemporaryServerPeer [(null)] - OnOutboundConnectionEstablished: sending init request
2015-07-22 14:57:01,541 [1] DEBUG MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonApplication [(null)] - Connection to master at 127.0.0.1:4520
2015-07-22 14:57:01,584 [1] INFO  Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - Application start: AppId=Login; AppPath=C:\Photon\deploy\ComplexServer, Type=LoginServer.LoginServer 
2015-07-22 14:57:01,592 [12] DEBUG Photon.SocketServer.ServerToServer.TemporaryServerPeer [(null)] - SentInitRequest: ConnID=2, ChannelId=0, result=Ok size=41 bytes
2015-07-22 14:57:02,157 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating AverageCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,163 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,167 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,171 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,175 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,178 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,182 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,185 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,188 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,191 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,195 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,198 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating CountsPerSecondCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,202 [13] DEBUG ExitGames.Diagnostics.Counter.CounterBase [(null)] - Creating NumericCounter: Name=''
2015-07-22 14:57:02,219 [15] DEBUG MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonApplication [(null)] - Received init request from sub server
2015-07-22 14:57:02,314 [15] DEBUG Photon.SocketServer.ServerToServer.ServerPeerBase [(null)] - SentOpRequest: ConnID=2, opCode=0, ChannelId=0 result=Ok size=439 bytes
2015-07-22 14:57:02,318 [15] DEBUG MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonApplication [(null)] - registering sub server

The following code's are from what i think to be the relevant classes.

PhotonRequest class:

```
class PhotonRequest : IMessage
{

    private readonly byte _code;
    private readonly Dictionary<byte, object> _parameters;
    private readonly int? _subCode;

    public PhotonRequest(byte code, int? subCode, Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
    {
        _code = code;
        _parameters = parameters;
        _subCode = subCode;
    }

    public short Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
    }


    public MessageType Type
    {
        get { return MessageType.Response; }
    }

    public int? SubCode
    {
        get { return _subCode; }
    }

    public Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
    }


    byte IMessage.Code
    {
        get {  throw new NotImplementedException();  }
    }

}
```

PhotonServerHandlerList class:

```
public class PhotonServerHandlerList
{

    private readonly DefaultRequestHandler _defaultRequestHandler;
    private readonly DefaultResponseHandler _defaultResponseHandler;
    private DefaultEventHandler _defaultEventHandler;

    protected readonly ILogger Log;

    private readonly Dictionary<int, PhotonServerHandler> _requestHandlerList;
    private readonly Dictionary<int, PhotonServerHandler> _responseHandlerList;
    private readonly Dictionary<int, PhotonServerHandler> _eventHandlerList;

    public PhotonServerHandlerList(IEnumerable<IHandler<PhotonServerPeer>> handlers, 
    DefaultRequestHandler defaultRequestHandler, DefaultResponseHandler defaultResponseHandler, 
        DefaultEventHandler defaultEventHandler, PhotonApplication application)
    {
        _defaultRequestHandler = defaultRequestHandler;
        _defaultResponseHandler = defaultResponseHandler;
        _defaultEventHandler = defaultEventHandler;

        Log = application.Log;

        _requestHandlerList = new Dictionary<int, PhotonServerHandler>();
        _responseHandlerList = new Dictionary<int, PhotonServerHandler>();
        _eventHandlerList = new Dictionary<int, PhotonServerHandler>();

        foreach (PhotonServerHandler handler in handlers)
        {
            if(!RegisterHandler(handler))
            {
                Log.WarnFormat("attempted to register handler {0} for type{1}|{2}", handler.GetType().Name, handler.Type, handler.Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool RegisterHandler(PhotonServerHandler handler)
    { 
        var registered = false;

        if((handler.Type & MessageType.Request) == MessageType.Request)
        {
            if (handler.SubCode.HasValue && !_requestHandlerList.ContainsKey(handler.SubCode.Value))
            {
                _requestHandlerList.Add(handler.SubCode.Value, handler);
                registered = true;
            }
            else if (!_requestHandlerList.ContainsKey(handler.Code))
            {
                _requestHandlerList.Add(handler.Code, handler);
                registered = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.ErrorFormat("RequestHandler list already contains handler for {0} - cannot add {1}", handler.Code, handler.GetType().Name);
            }

        }

        if ((handler.Type & MessageType.Response) == MessageType.Response)
        {
            if (handler.SubCode.HasValue && !_responseHandlerList.ContainsKey(handler.SubCode.Value))
            {
                _responseHandlerList.Add(handler.SubCode.Value, handler);
                registered = true;
            }
            else if (!_responseHandlerList.ContainsKey(handler.Code))
            {
                _responseHandlerList.Add(handler.Code, handler);
                registered = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.ErrorFormat("Response Handler list already contains handler for {0} - cannot add {1}", handler.Code, handler.GetType().Name);
            }

        }

        if ((handler.Type & MessageType.Async) == MessageType.Async)
        {
            if (handler.SubCode.HasValue && !_eventHandlerList.ContainsKey(handler.SubCode.Value))
            {
                _eventHandlerList.Add(handler.SubCode.Value, handler);
                registered = true;
            }
            else if (!_eventHandlerList.ContainsKey(handler.Code))
            {
                _eventHandlerList.Add(handler.Code, handler);
                registered = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.ErrorFormat("event Handler list already contains handler for {0} - cannot add {1}", handler.Code, handler.GetType().Name);
            }

        }

        return registered;
    }

    public bool HandleMessage(IMessage message, PhotonServerPeer peer)
    {
        bool handled = false;

        switch (message.Type)
        { 
            case MessageType.Request:
                if (message.SubCode.HasValue && _requestHandlerList.ContainsKey(message.SubCode.Value))
                {
                    _requestHandlerList[message.SubCode.Value].HandleMessage(message, peer);
                    handled = true;
                }
                else if (!message.SubCode.HasValue && _requestHandlerList.ContainsKey(message.Code))
                {
                    _requestHandlerList[message.Code].HandleMessage(message, peer);
                    handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _defaultRequestHandler.HandleMessage(message, peer);
                }
                break;

            case MessageType.Response:
                if (message.SubCode.HasValue && _responseHandlerList.ContainsKey(message.SubCode.Value))
                {
                    _responseHandlerList[message.SubCode.Value].HandleMessage(message, peer);
                    handled = true;
                }
                else if (!message.SubCode.HasValue && _responseHandlerList.ContainsKey(message.Code))
                {
                    _responseHandlerList[message.Code].HandleMessage(message, peer);
                    handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _defaultResponseHandler.HandleMessage(message, peer);
                }
                break;

            case MessageType.Async:
                if (message.SubCode.HasValue && _eventHandlerList.ContainsKey(message.SubCode.Value))
                {
                    _eventHandlerList[message.SubCode.Value].HandleMessage(message, peer);
                    handled = true;
                }
                else if (!message.SubCode.HasValue && _eventHandlerList.ContainsKey(message.Code))
                {
                    _eventHandlerList[message.Code].HandleMessage(message, peer);
                    handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _defaultEventHandler.HandleMessage(message, peer);
                }
                break;
        }

        return handled;
    }
}
```

IMessage interface:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    MessageType Type { get; }
    byte Code { get; }
    int? SubCode { get; } // nullable int
    Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not familiar with what you are doing, this stands out to me in that wall of debug text:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not
>   implemented. at
>   MMO.Photon.Application.PhotonRequest.MMO.Framework.IMessage.get_Code()
>   in
>   c:\Programming\SoftwareDevelopment\C#\MMO\MMO.Photon\Application\PhotonRequest.cs:line
>   48

Your `PhotonRequest` class inherits the `IMessage` interface which is an obligation to implement it as it is prescribed by the interface. You currently declare `Code` as follows in your class:

```
public short Code
{
    get
    {
        return _code;
    }
}
```

Whereas it is declared in the `IMessage` interface as:

```
byte Code { get; }
```

You need to change the type of your's to `byte` instead of `short`. I'm not sure how this built for you (as the Visual Studio C# compiler would throw a compiler error on this), but it would be that.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the lack of description, this stuff is still relatively new to me. I will update the topic with the IMessage's code. And yeah i forgot to post that I had already changed the modifier on it by adding public, it also threw an error: "The modifier public is not valid for this item"

Comment: I found the issue. One moment.

Comment: Awesome. Im actually quite embarrassed... Was a much easier error than I thought... For 1, I had a duplicate of that small method, which was causing it to throw up. 2, the duplicated method, for some reason, had the 'throw new not implemented exception' which I have no idea how it even got there. And 3, the sub server was searching for a the byte, but it wasn't returninganything which caused it to throw the error. I REALLY appreciate that you helped so quickly, and so simply put.

Comment: No problem. Glad I helped identify the issue. Don't forget to upvote and mark as the accepted answer. :)